# Virtualenv transfer from Mac to Windows

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenv-commands

I am currently working on a Django project that uses Virtualenv. Originally, I started the project on my Mac, and would activate the virtual env by entering:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

since the virtual env files are stored in a folder called "ENV" and the path to the activate file is: "env/bin/activate." However, I recently stared using a Windows PC as my second computer, and have used Git to clone the project on to the Windows PC. However, I can not start the virtualenv on my Windows PC. These are the commands I have tried thus far:

```
source env/bin/activate
source env\bin\activate
env/bin/activate    
env\bin\activate
```

And I get the error:

```
The term '\ENV\bin\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
```

ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
I have pip and virtualenv installed on my Windows PC, anyone know how I can activate my virtualenv?

Comment: I really don't like to be that guy that says RTFM but really - Read the manual. "In a newly created virtualenv there will be a bin/activate shell script. For Windows systems, activation scripts are provided for CMD.exe and Powershell."  http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html

Comment: Thanks, I ran through the manual before posting. This isn't a newly created  virtualenv, but one I created on my Mac, and cloned to my PC using Git.